# DetailViewControllers content cut off

Tags: swift, master-detail

I am using apples template for a master-detail app and I was wondering: if I am displaying the content on an iPad or any other device with a horizontal size class which is regular. The content on the DetailViewController is cut off when I am open the MasterViewController.
[image]

DetailViewController:

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var detailDescriptionLabel: UILabel!


func configureView() {
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.
    if let detail = detailItem {
        if let label = detailDescriptionLabel {
            label.text = detail.description
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    configureView()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

var detailItem: NSDate? {
    didSet {
        // Update the view.
        configureView()
    }
}


}
```

MasterViewController:

```
import UIKit

class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {

    var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
    var objects = [Any]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem

        let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(insertNewObject(_:)))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
        if let split = splitViewController {
            let controllers = split.viewControllers
            detailViewController = (controllers[controllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as? DetailViewController
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = splitViewController!.isCollapsed
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @objc
    func insertNewObject(_ sender: Any) {
        objects.insert(NSDate(), at: 0)
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }

    // MARK: - Segues

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let object = objects[indexPath.row] as! NSDate
                let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
                controller.detailItem = object
                controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
                controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Table View

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return objects.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

        let object = objects[indexPath.row] as! NSDate
        cell.textLabel!.text = object.description
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            objects.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: What constraints have you got set on `detailDescriptionLabel` ?

Comment: It‘s centered horizontally and vertically

Comment: And furthermore the title of my navigation bar is also not in the center anymore

Comment: Just tap the Details View controller and Master View Controller will be rolled out. You have posted the code from Apple Template, lol)

Comment: i want my content to be displayed correctly while the MasterViewController is rolled out like in the iOS settings for example

Comment: @Dmitry is correct in what he says, and this is intended behaviour when in Portrait mode.  To prevent that, I have posted solution below as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to `viewDidLoad` in `MasterViewController`:

```
splitViewController?.preferredDisplayMode = .allVisible
```

Comment: How did you find out?

Comment: I've used it before.  Once you said you wanted it to work like the Settings App, I knew what you meant.

Comment: I didn‘t find any solution on the internet. Sometimes the solution is so "easy". Thanks dude.

Comment: You're welcome.  The reference is here if you want it.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisplitviewcontroller/1623170-preferreddisplaymode